# What are the relationships between the three vectors in $\vec a • (\vec b × \vec c)$?

Tags: vectors

I'm given this task:

> Given a = [-5, 8, 1] and  b = [2, -7, -3], find
>
> 1. a × b and verify that it is perpendicular to both a and b
> 2. Avector c such that a • (b × c) = 0
>
> What is the relationship between the vectors  a, b and c in this case, and why? Verify this.

I have already done the points 1 and 2, but I'm not sure about my answer to the "What is the relationship between the vectors  a, b and c in this case, and why? Verify this."

So far I've found that a and c have to be collinear, but otherwise I see no other relationships. However it feels like there should be more, so am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a\cdot(b \times c)=(a \times b) \cdot c=0$

This implies $c$ is perpendicular to $a \times b$.

So what's the relation with $c$ and  $a,b$ ? (Note: $a \times b$ is perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$).

Do you observe that c is parallel to the plane spanned by a and b?

therefore c= xa+yb for some x,y in R.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. So their relationship is that they are coplanar.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Try to visualize.

Comment: I did, and I do see how that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

By 2. (given $c \neq0$):

1. Either $c$ is linearly-dependent on $b$ (In this case $b \times c=0$).
2. Or, $a$ is orthogonal to $b \times c$, therefore $a$ lies in a plain spanned by $\{b,c\}$.
   In other words, $a$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $b$ and $c$.
   i.e., there exist 2 scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ not both $0$ such that:
   $$a=\lambda_1b+\lambda_1c$$